# How to return array from a Delphi function?

Tags: arrays, delphi

I have a function in my application that needs to return an array. I have found in a couple of places how to do this by declaring the array type, e.g.

```
type
  TStringArray = array of string;
```

And then declaring my function

```
function SomeFunction(SomeParam: Integer): TStringArray;
```

My problem is trying to set this up in a form that has both interface and implementation. How do I declare my type and have a function declaration with that type in the interface ?

Comment: "Array of string" is usually considered "not idiomatic" in Delphi.  TStringList is usually preferred.

Comment: I usually use the "DynArray" suffix for naming such type definition, in order to make a distinction between a dynamic and a static array: `TStringDynArray = array of string; TStringArray = array[0..(maxInt div sizeof(string))-1] of string;` But there is no official convention about it.

Comment: @Warren P: Note that the new `FileIO` unit uses which is part of the XE RTL uses `TStringDynArray` extensively. So I don't agree that it is not idiomatic. Especially if you want to return the array and loop over it using an enumerator this is very convenient (see `TDirectory.GetFiles` for an example).

Comment: @Warren P: One more point: returning a `TStringList` is even less idiomatic, beacause it violates the "creator is responsible for destruction" principle

Comment: Typically, I would pass in a string list instead, Smasher. That means I would write `SomeFunction(other_parameters; outData:TStringList):Boolean;` or  `SomeProcedure(other_parameters; outData:TStringList);`.   It's also not idiomatic to return an allocated object, as you say.   So don't.

Comment: @Smasher: Who uses FileIO?  Whoever wrote that is going against a convention observed almost universally elsewhere in the RTL and VCL.

Comment: What's the point of this convention? I find `for FileName in TDirectory.GetFiles do ...` so much more elegant than 
`StrList := TStringList.Create; try TDirectory.GetFiles (StrList); for FileName in StrList do ... finally StrList.Free; end;` Are there any disadvantages of the array approach? Otherwise there's no reason not to use it IMHO

Comment: BTW: I was talking about `IOUtils` of course

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses SysUtils;

type
  TStringArray = array of string;

function SomeFunction(SomeParam: integer): TStringArray;

...

implementation

function SomeFunction(SomeParam: integer): TStringArray;
begin
  SetLength(result, 3);
  result[0] := 'Alpha';
  result[1] := 'Beta';
  result[2] := 'Gamma';
end;

...

end.
```

The golden rule is that the `interface` section of a unit describes the data types used by the unit, and the types, classes and functions (their signatures) that reside in the unit. This is what all *other* units see. The `implementation` section contains the implementation of the classes and functions. This is not visible to other units. Other units need to care about the interface of the unit, the 'contract' signed by this unit and the external unit, not the 'implementation details' found in the implementation section.

Answer (score 20):

If you Delphi is fairly recent, you don't need to declare a new type, by declaring it as `TArray<String>`.

Example copied and pasted from the answer above:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

function SomeFunction(SomeParam: integer): TArray<String>;

implementation

function SomeFunction(SomeParam: integer): TArray<String>;
begin
  SetLength(result, 3);
  result[0] := 'Alpha';
  result[1] := 'Beta';
  result[2] := 'Gamma';
end;

end.
```

Comment: `TArray<T>` (and Generics in general) is not without some problems though, so be careful with it.