# function to return an array of Integer delphi

Tags: arrays, function, delphi

So I have a function that takes a dataset and needs to return all values from a field. I can't figure out how to make the function return an array, as when I declare an array I keep get the error

```
[DCC Error] dataModuleImportMonetar.pas(20): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'nr'
```

Here is my code

```
unit dataModuleImportMonetar;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, DB, ADODB;

type
  TDataModule2 = class(TDataModule)
    conn: TADOConnection;
    importMonetar: TADOStoredProc;

    qMonetare: TADOQuery;
  private
    { Private declarations }
    //nr  : Array[Word] of Integer;
    nr : IntegerArray;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    function nrFisiere ( dataSet : TDataSet) : nr ;
  end;

var
  DataModule2: TDataModule2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TDataModule2 }

function TDataModule2.nrFisiere(dataSet: TDataSet): nr;
 var
  i : Integer;
begin
       dataSet.First;

       for i := 0 to dataSet.RecordCount  do
         begin
          Return nr[i] := dataSet.FieldByName('nrMonetare').Value;
         end;

end;


end.
```

What Am I doing wrong? How cand I declare a  function that will return an array of Integer

For @TLama

If I do that ( already did before asking )

```
 type
  TDataModule2 = class(TDataModule)
    conn: TADOConnection;
    importMonetar: TADOStoredProc;
    TIntArray : array of Integer;
    qMonetare: TADOQuery;
```

I get an othe error `[DCC Error] dataModuleImportMonetar.pas(12): E2217 Published field 'TIntArray' not a class or interface type`

Comment: You must define a `type`, not declare a variable.

Comment: Can you be more specific, I don't follow...

Comment: [`Like this`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6145935/960757) for instance.

Comment: @TLama If I do that I get an other error... I just don't get it.

Comment: If you write that `TIntArray: array of Integer;` line inside the class definition, then you're declaring a field. You must write it outside the class, e.g. [`this way`](http://pastebin.com/ehUHSqMT).

Comment: Using a field of type IntegerArray is a very bad idea as it is declared as   `IntegerArray  = array[0..$effffff] of Integer;`. Thus the field nr will occupy about 1GB of memory.

Comment: So do you have a better solution?

Comment: TLama showed you the declaration of a dynamic array. In addition the use of Return inside the function reveals that you seem to be not very familiar with the Delphi syntax. I assume a basic course - be it a book or from a tutor.

Comment: I am familiar to most of the delphi sintax, but not with any kind of array, I rarely use them.

Comment: @TLama your paste-bin link has a typo. You declared the type with `:` instead of `=`.

Comment: CiucaS Your edit is not **NOT** doing what @TLama told you to do, please read his first link properly. And reading the second please note the typo I mention in my previous comment. A very important skill in programming is _precision_. You cannot afford to be sloppy in how you follow instructions. You also have to be precise in defining and understanding what your code is doing. Programming languages are not like natural languages where H.I. (human "intelligence") can compensate for errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `TIntegerDynArray` from `Types.pas`.
If you are using a Delphi Version >= 2010 you could also use `TArray<Integer>`.

```
unit dataModuleImportMonetar;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, DB, ADODB, Types;

type
  TDataModule2 = class(TDataModule)
    conn: TADOConnection;
    importMonetar: TADOStoredProc;

    qMonetare: TADOQuery;
  public
    function nrFisiere(dataSet: TDataSet): TIntegerDynArray;
  end;

var
  DataModule2: TDataModule2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

{ TDataModule2 }

function TDataModule2.nrFisiere(dataSet: TDataSet): TIntegerDynArray;
var
  i: Integer;
  f: TField;
begin
  dataSet.First;
  SetLength(Result, dataSet.RecordCount);
  i := 0;
  // remember the field to avoid calling FieldByName in a loop
  f := dataSet.FieldByName('nrMonetare'); 
  while not dataSet.Eof do
  begin
    Result[i] := f.Value;
    Inc(i);
    dataSet.Next;
  end;
end;

end.
```